# How to emit signal in KWin scripting API

Tags: javascript, kde-plasma

With the KWin scripting API, I know I can connect a signal with

```
client.signal.connect(myFunction);
```

to trigger some action when the script receives a signal.

But how can I emit a signal from my KWin script for other components to pick up?

I want something like

```
client.emit(signal);
```

but couldn't find anything in the API documentation and unsuccessfully tried various possible syntaxes.

My use case is that I want to emit a `clientStartUserMovedResized` signal before doing a geometry change, so that another script can detect that a window is about to be changed with the window with the old geometry passed over, before the `clientGeometryChanged` signal is automatically emitted after the change in geometry has already happened and the old geometry is lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered on reddit https://old.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/qndb0k/how_to_emit_signal_in_kwin_scripting_api/

Pretty sure you just call it as a normal function.

- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#signal-handler-attributes
- https://develop.kde.org/docs/plasma/kwin/api/#signals-3
- `client.clientStartUserMovedResized(client)` (not sure why it needs a references to itself as a parameter)
- https://invent.kde.org/plasma/kwin/-/blob/master/src/abstract_client.cpp#L970